# Accessing ADO.NET metadata

Tags: c#, ado.net, metadata, wcf-ria-services, visual-studio-lightswitch

I am creating an application that requires extended SQL properties. With the help of a colleague those properties have been appended to my edmx model.

All I need to do now is somehow pull this data (maybe into a table?) in a WCF RIA service which will then be used within LightSwitch. When debugging I can see the metadata I need, but am unsure of how to extract this.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean about "appended to my edmx model"?

Comment: Hi robert, I have used a script that writes extended SQL properties to the .edmx file. Hope this clarifies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a workaround for this(although not particulary elegant) by using XML to find the extended metadata I want and returning that to a simple POCO table. Let me know if theres a better way.

Cheers